# Help troubleshoot MySQL memory usage, indexes without joins, save-point rollbacks

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

I noticed that the memory usage for mysqld keeps growing over time. The sites hosted are quite low traffic, though they're mostly Magento installations (which is known to be a bit of a hog).

I tuned some settings from a separate question I asked a while ago which you can view [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187505/mysql-optimizations).

I feel that the biggest culprit is the slow queries (though it doesn't show in the mysqltuner report since I have it currently set quite high), joins performed without indexes, and/or save point rollbacks. It's just that I have no clue where to start in resolving it.

Would greatly appreciate some guidance.

I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but I'm not an expert in MySQL.

This is a dedicated server with about 15 sites and about half of them are Magento 1 installations. All sites are fairly low traffic. 16GB of total RAM is on the server which is used for all services (MySQL, httpd, mail, etc)

Requested files: 
[zip-2017-02-05](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4q1883zq3ucyw4z/dba_196767_20180205.zip?dl=0) | 
[zip-2017-02-07](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yk2xs0z9y37amod/dba_196767_20180207.zip?dl=0)

[php.ini](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3ceub1pbtmz3wq/php.ini?dl=0)

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]                                                                                                                            

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/chroot/tmp/mysql.sock

userstat=1


ft_min_word_len=3

max_connections=100 # MAX CURRENT X 5
max_connect_errors=25
connect_timeout=10
interactive_timeout=20
wait_timeout=50
delayed_insert_timeout=10
#join_buffer_size=1M

max_allowed_packet=16M

myisam_sort_buffer_size=1M
#sort_buffer_size=1M

#read_buffer_size=1M
#read_rnd_buffer_size=2M

thread_cache_size=100  # from 192 MySQL v 8 recommends CAP of 100 to avoid overload
thread_concurrency=4

query_cache_size=100M # from 256M
#query_cache_limit=32M #remove to allow default of 1M rather than 32M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_min_res_unit = 512  # from 4K to conserve qcache RAM used per RESULT

tmp_table_size=80M # from 512M
max_heap_table_size=80M # from 512M
max_tmp_tables=10
slow_query_log=1
long_query_time=10
slow-query-log-file  = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
table_open_cache = 10000  # 10000 from 2000 to support the 28,000 opened by instance

innodb-file-per-table=1

character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci

# Tweaking below
# 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G  # to match RAM reported by MySQLTuner
# 512 MB
key_buffer_size = 256M  # from 512M used only my MyISAM
# 16MB
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 4
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0
skip-external-locking
# Double write off :)
innodb_doublewrite = true
low_priority_updates = 1
#innodb_checksums = false
innodb_support_xa = false
max_write_lock_count = 10
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 40
innodb_io_capacity = 400
innodb_write_io_threads = 4
innodb_read_io_threads = 4
innodb_adaptive_flushing = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_print_all_deadlocks = 1 # to error log, if you ever have one, you will WISH you had the details. 
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=1 # from OFF to allow quick warmup 
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=1 #from OFF to allow warmed buffer_pool
#skip-name-resolve=1
#log_error_verbosity=3 
log_warnings = 2 # to record Aborted Connections in error.log
```

mysqltuner.pl (Updated 02/05/2018 05:13PM)

```
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 96M (Tables: 302)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 964M (Tables: 3988)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 3M (Tables: 158)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There are 612 basic passwords in the list.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 26d 6h 45m 47s (43M q [18.957 qps], 1M conn, TX: 59G, RX: 13G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 57% / 43%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 15.5G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 5.1G
[--] Other process memory: 1.3G
[--] Total buffers: 4.4G global + 1.1M per thread (100 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 555M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 5.0G (32.22% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 5.1G (32.76% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (4/43M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 23% (23/100)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.01%  (201/1369212)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 91.1% (31M cached / 34M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 51145
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (74 temp sorts / 528K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 32913
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 24% (315K on disk / 1M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (23 created / 1M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 75% (8K open / 11K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 4% (812/20K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (8M immediate / 8M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 555.4M
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 8 thread(s).
[!!] thread_pool_size between 16 and 36 when using InnoDB storage engine.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 19.8% (53M used / 268M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 256.0M/23.2M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (6M cached / 3K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 69.2% (92K cached / 64K writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 4
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 4.0G/964.1M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (50 %): 1.0G * 2/4.0G should be equal 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (1171708542 hits/ 1171766170 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 55.47% (2772358 hits/ 4997589 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 2225231 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server.

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
    Thread pool size for InnoDB usage (8)
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_size (> 100M)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    thread_pool_size between 16 and 36 for InnoDB usage
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=512M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=4)
```

mysqltuner.pl (Updated 02/07/2018 07:16PM)

```
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 96M (Tables: 302)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 969M (Tables: 3988)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 3M (Tables: 158)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There are 612 basic passwords in the list.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 28d 8h 50m 27s (46M q [18.909 qps], 1M conn, TX: 63G, RX: 14G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 58% / 42%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 15.5G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 5.1G
[--] Other process memory: 1.4G
[--] Total buffers: 4.4G global + 1.1M per thread (100 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 555M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 5.0G (32.22% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 5.1G (32.76% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (4/46M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 23% (23/100)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.02%  (247/1484045)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 90.9% (33M cached / 36M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 52710
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (79 temp sorts / 605K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 35942
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 24% (339K on disk / 1M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (23 created / 1M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 74% (8K open / 11K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 4% (814/20K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (9M immediate / 9M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 555.4M
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 8 thread(s).
[!!] thread_pool_size between 16 and 36 when using InnoDB storage engine.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 19.8% (53M used / 268M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 256.0M/23.2M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (7M cached / 3K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 69.4% (99K cached / 68K writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 4
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 4.0G/969.7M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (50 %): 1.0G * 2/4.0G should be equal 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (1664350899 hits/ 1664408544 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 54.89% (2958719 hits/ 5390689 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 2431970 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server.

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
    Thread pool size for InnoDB usage (8)
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_size (> 100M)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    thread_pool_size between 16 and 36 for InnoDB usage
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=512M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=4)
```

Comment: RAM nnn TB/GB/MB on your Host server, indicate DEDICATED or SHARED w other apps 
current complete my.cnf/ini, php.ini (if used)
On 2/5 and 2/7/18 for comparison, Please include:
 Text results of: 
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop   OR  top for most active apps
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
MySQLTuner.com  entire report

Comment: Yeah, I'm always messing up on that. Still a newbie on this. I'll update those.

Comment: I've updated my.cnf and php.ini. Will update on Monday with the other data. Thanks again.

Comment: Another possible idea for your analysis toolkit:
https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/user-beancounters-ubc-parameters/
If you could 
A) cat /proc/user_beancounters >beancounters-20180205.txt  and 
B) cat /proc/user_beancounters >beancounters-20180207.txt
we could compare resources used in this weeks efforts to determine
where your memory is going.  
Please gather your data about the same time of day - no shutdowns/restarts, please.

Comment: I've updated the post with latest mysqltuner.pl results, along with a zip file containing the requested command results. 

In regards to beancounters, it's saying no such file or directory.

Comment: Were you at the same Linux prompt as when you ran -limit -a?
The file could have moved from proc to another folder, search for it from your base directory.

Comment: Is there only one instance of `mysqld` running?  Based on your my.cnf, I would expect it to stop growing at maybe 6GB of RAM.  How big did it grow to?

Comment: @rickjames Looking at the mysqltuner posted report, your expectations match the reported value. Good job.

Comment: @enyceexdanny  Please ask for help on a single topic in the future.  You will more likely get a reasonable single response.

Comment: @rickjames Yes, it's only one instance my mysqld. And I've never left it long enough to grow to 6GB to be honest. It wasn't intentional, but ended up restarting server due to maintenance.

Comment: @wilson hauck I will, thanks and sorry about that. I did update the new results for mysqltuner.pl and the files. It's updated on the original post as a new zip file.

Comment: @enyceexdanny  top report of 2/7/2018 has ~ 300 tasks using memory and many of the tasks are using VIRT memory.  Could we use SKYPE to talk about the details I am seeing?  Wilson Hauck Birmingham AL
In the 2/5/2018 and 2/7/2018 top reports, there appeared to be stranded USERS in the list and multiple copies of programs running,   Could your turn on General Log, have a typical user login, run a couple of queries, logoff, Same user login/logout quickly.  Five minutes LATER Turn General Log off.  Post it in a zip?  Hoping to catch a savepoint_rollback in the General log.  Thanks..

Comment: @enyceexdanny  If you click on my name in any comment or answer, you will be on a page where you can click Network Profile for me.  or you.  NIce recap shows up.

Comment: "currently set quite high" -- It sounds like you know the next step, but have not done it??  Set `long_query_time=1`; run for a day; get `pt-query-digest`.